# UML Diagrams: Can I use same actor on one diagram couple of times?

Tags: uml, actor

I am drawing some diagram, and I am wondering if it is acceptable for the actor to be in diagram more than once (for better transparency of the diagram)?

Thanks

Comment: I think UML allows it, but I would not consider it a best practice. If you are facing this issue then you are probably trying to show too much on a single diagram.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UMLDiagram` is a composition of `UMLDiagramElement`s, however `Actor` is **NOT** `UmlDiagramElement`, it is an `Element`. The `UMLDiagramElement` counterpart for Actor is either `UMLShape` (when shown as icon/figure) or `UMLClassifierShape` (when shown as a class box).

You have to keep the concepts of "UML Model" and "UML Diagram" separate. Model is a conceptual representation of your domain, and diagram is a concrete visual representation of a model.

The two elements from Model and Diagram are then connected by an association (B.2.2).
[image]

The association is N:M (and unidirectional), the model doesn't care that it is being visualized.

As far as I can tell **there is nothing that would restrict you from having several visual representations of a single actor.**

Lastly as both Thomas and Geert mentioned, **it is a bad practice**. If your diagram is so complex that you want multiple representations you should probably decompose it.

Answer (score 2):

Although UML does not forbid to use the same element more than once on a diagram, this is no good practice. Having the same UML element more than once on a diagram leads to confusion of the diagram reader. If you have the need to un-clutter connectors you probably already ran into a spider-web diagram style and you're better off to create several smaller diagrams.

Think of the implication: if any element appears more than once, then how would you know they are the same. This would lead to more confusion than it would actually help.

Comment: I don't think that this restriction applies, because you can have multiple instances of diagram elements pointing to the same model elements.

Comment: @Peter see my addition