# Use case diagram - primary and secondary actor at the same time

Tags: uml, actor, use-case, use-case-diagram

Can an actor be both primary and secondary in an extended management system?

e.g. Warehouse worker [use case] **displays the list of orders** to be packed (as secondary actor), then [use cases] **packs the order, marks the order as ready** (as primary actor)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, an actor can be both [primary and secondary](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/types-of-actor-in-use-case-model/) in the same diagram:

- The qualification “primary” vs “secondary” is use-case per use-case:  A use-case expresses an actor goal. The **primary actor** is the one who has such a goal.  **Secondary actors** are any other actors involved in the use case to help achieving the goal of the primary actor.
- Occasionally, "primary" and "secondary" for the system as a whole system, but with a slightly different meaning:  primary actors are then those for whom the system is made.
- **UML** does not define nor even use the terminology of “primary” and “secondary” actors.  Moreover,  UML leaves the semantics  of multiple actors for a same use-case **unspecified**.
- By the way the use-case community tends nowadays to prefer the term of “**supporting actor**” rather than “secondary actor”. (Secondary sounds as if they were less important or even optional, whereas supporting suggests better that these are as important as the primary actor).

Comment: I came here wondering if an actor that is both primary and supporting on the same diagram should appear on both the left and right side of the diagram, by convention.

Comment: @dangerginger I’d try to avoid it, because obviously the actor point of view might get lost on the way. But it is allowed to show multiple times the same model element in a diagram. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34372262/3723423